# When using yacc, how do you tell yyparse() that you want to stop parsing?

Tags: parsing, error-handling, yacc

Still learning yacc and flex, and ran across a scenario that the how-to's and tutorials that I have do not cover. I am trying to parse a file, and as I'm going along, I'm doing some secondary error checking in the code I've placed in my `parser.y` file. When I come across something that is lexicographically correct (that is, the parse matches properly) but logically incorrect (unexpected value or inappropriate value), how do I get `yyparse` to exit? Also, can I have it return an error code back to me that I can check for in my calling code?

```
/* Sample */
my_file_format:
  header body_lines footer
  ;
header:
  OBRACE INT CBRACE
  |
  OBRACE STRING CBRACE {
    if ( strcmp ( $1, "Contrived_Example" ) != 0 ) { /* I want to exit here */ }
  }
  ;
/* etc ... */
```

I realize that in my example I can simply look for "Contrived_Example" using a rule, but my point is in the `if`-block -- can I tell `yyparse` that I want to stop parsing here?

Comment: Why? You don't want to quit on the first error. You want to parse the whole file and report all the errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the macros `YYERROR` or `YYABORT` depending on what exactly you want.  `YYABORT` causes yyparse to immediately return with a failure, while `YYERROR` causes it to act as if there's been an error and try to recover (which will return failure if it can't recover).

You can also use `YYACCEPT` to cause yyparse to immediately return success.

Comment: +1 almost what I want - it does exit out of the parsing, albeit in a rather abrupt manner.

Comment: @Will 'Abrupt' is exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I want to stop parsing when lexing, and YYERROR, YYABORT may be unavaliable. You can just return YYerror, which has defined in y.tab.h, like this:
`'[^'\n]*$       { yyerror("Unterminated string");  return YYerror;}`
Why it works? firstly executes lex() when yacc parsing and if the function returns YYerror, it goes to yyerrlab1.

Comment: May be unavailable why?